# UIButton selected state change image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I know this should be very simple but since I really have looked around here and on google without getting my code to work I will ask. Yes, I have checked related questions and they does not work...

I simply want to change the image of the button when it is pressed.

This is my header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;

@end
```

And my implementation file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

    [self.myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

}
@end
```

The button is built and connected in Main.storyBoard and I have also tried to do it in the attributes inspector but neither way worked!

[image]

Please note that I am not looking for how to do highlighted state but selected.

Comment: try the name of the image without  ".png" and check if the image is really exist

Comment: I have tried to remove ".png" and since the image is working for "normal state" it should work for selected state

Comment: to test try to added the code after adding the images: `self.myButton.selected = YES;`

Comment: nope, did not work :)

Comment: I have checked it, thanks. But it did not changed the image when state is selected...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe what you need to do is set the button's state to selected when the button is tapped. Probably something like this:

```
-(IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    if(self.myButton.selected)
        [self.mybytton setSelected:NO];
    else
        [self.mybutton setSelected:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You need to set the image for each state from your interface builder and you don't need to add a code if you want :

Select  the `State Config` to `Default` and then choose an image

[image: Default state]

Select  the `State Config` to `Selected` and then choose an image

[image: Selected]

And now to test each state of the button:

[image: button states]

You can do the same for background image just select the parameter `"Background"`

Comment: did you try to set the background image instead of the image

Comment: yes, I have tried every option in interface builder that I know... including this one

Comment: Yes, I can test if the button goes in selected mode and the image changes - and yes, it changes in Interface builder but when running the app and pressing the button it behaves like "highlighted" and not "selected"...

Comment: I don't know why nobody had upvoted this answer as yet! Thanks @Aladin for such an easy solution rather than setting every image from code

Answer (score 2):

Change to whatever image you need in the IB builder in the State Config and add an action to that button and in that add this line of code as said by @Aladin.

```
   @IBAction func btnPressed (_ sender: UIButton) {

    // If you want to change it for selected state when tapped. 
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a method for when the button is clicked? If yes, put this below lines in there:

```
[self.myButton setSelected:YES];
[self.myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: `- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self.toggleChange setSelected:YES];
    [self.toggleChange setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"info-22.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}` did not work

Answer (score 0):

Why not try to set background image default to "normal.png";

```
[self.mybutton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normal.png"]];
```

And switch to "selected.png" when perform the button.

```
[self.mybutton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"]];
```

Comment: ERROR: No visible @interface for 'UIButton' declares the selector 'setBackgroundImage:'